# openapi-generator with spring-boot, remove generated values

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, openapi-generator

I'm using openapi-generator for gradle.

Config:

```
task generateSalesOffersApi(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask){
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/my-contract.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "${buildDir}/generated".toString()
    additionalProperties = [
            interfaceOnly: 'true',
            reactive: 'true',
            skipDefaultInterface: "true",
            implicitHeaders: "true",
    ]

    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary: 'java8',
            swaggerDocketConfig: "true",
            useTags:  'false',
            apiPackage: 'com.data.api',
            modelPackage: 'com.data.model',
    ]

    systemProperties = [
            apis: "",
            models: "",
            hideGenerationTimestamp: "true"
    ]
```

The models are generated as expected. Api part mostly too.

But how to get rid of **ResponseEntity** wrapping and **ServerWebExchange** as method param in generated interfaces.

Actual:

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>> getMyPojo(@ApiParam(value = "Param 1",required=true) @PathVariable("param1") String param1, ServerWebExchange exchange);
```

Expected:

```
Mono<MyPojo> getMyPojo(@ApiParam(value = "Param 1",required=true) @PathVariable("param1") String param1);
```

I tried to use the java generator where you can set the library to **webclient**, but unfortunately this was missing a lot of configuration for me and was generating many unnecessary classes.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve your issue? Do you have solution about it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to set `reactive` to `false`:

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md

> **reactive**
>
> wrap responses in Mono/Flux Reactor types (spring-boot only)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I went off with the actual and expected part. I updated the question with correct inputs.